# Programming PHP - what to expect when tr ansitioning from PC to Mac?

Tags: php, windows, macos, wampserver

I'm investigating replacements for my venerable Thinkpad T61. One option is to go with one of the Apple laptops. I exclusively do web development right now, so PHP, Javascript, etc. I currently use WAMPServer & Eclipse as my main tools.

If I were to transition to a Mac, what should I expect with regard to programming for the web? Where should I expect to see major changes?

Comment: major change: forced to worship at the Altar of Jobs instead of at the Altar of Gates.

Comment: I think this would be better suited to http://superuser.com/ than SO.

Comment: @MarcB Gates Altar lets you do lots, but randomly catches fire. Jobs Altar only allows kow-towing, but is amazingly beautiful and has many many followers.

Comment: major change: you'll see more apples and less windows

Comment: Time to get a Linux desktop! As a PHP developer though you shouldn't see a great deal of difference

Comment: Time to start using virtualboxes; making you platform independent

Comment: You may see more case sensitivity in paths on Mac but you shouldn't be taking advantage of Windows case insensitivity anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest change would be if you're using PHP to open local files with absolute path:

On OS X, you will use the format similar to `/home/jdelage/workspace/web/` instead of `C:\users\jdelage\workspace\web`. Make sure you update all your code to forward slashes instead of backslashes - forward slashes [work on both platorms](http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary)

Installing optional PHP modules will be a little different, but should be easier on OS X.

There are few other corner case items items but remember that PHP is designed to be cross-platform, and tries hard to abstract the underlying OS away from you.